# Prove $\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/p))\subset \mathbb{Q}(e^{i2\pi/p})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, trigonometry, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I'm solving problems from my galois theory course to practice for my exam and I found this one:

> Calculate the degree of the minimal polinomial of $\cos(2\pi/p)$ over
> $\mathbb{Q}$, where $p$ is a prime number. Hint: compare the
> appropiate extension to $\mathbb{Q}(e^{i2\pi/p})/\mathbb{Q}$.

I followed the hint and found that $[\mathbb{Q}(e^{i2\pi/p}):\mathbb{Q}]=p$ (correct me if I'm wrong), because given that $p$ is prime, $\{1,e^{i2\pi/p},e^{i2\pi\cdot2/p},\dots, e^{i2\pi(p-1)/p}\}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent (thought I'm not pretty sure if this is trivial or how can I prove it anyway), while $\{1,e^{i2\pi/p},e^{i2\pi\cdot2/p},\dots, e^{i2\pi(p-1)/p},e^{i2\pi p/p}=1\}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly dependent, so this gives the result that $[\mathbb{Q}(e^{i2\pi/p}):\mathbb{Q}]=p$.

Now, if I prove $\cos(2\pi/p)\in\mathbb{Q}(e^{i2\pi/p})$, for generation minimality I conclude  $\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/p))\subset \mathbb{Q}(e^{i2\pi/p})$ and can use degree transitivity to find that $[\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/p)):\mathbb{Q}]$ is either $p$ or $1$ (I don't know yet which of this is the case). I'm stuck here, proving $\cos(2\pi/p)\in\mathbb{Q}(e^{i2\pi/p})$ and then finding if either $\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/p))=\mathbb{Q}(e^{i2\pi/p})$ or either $\mathbb{Q})\cos(2\pi/p))=\mathbb{Q}$.

How can I end this? Is my reasoning till this point correct? If not, please correct me. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the formula $$\cos (a) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{ia} + (e^{ia})^{-1})$$

Comment: @Crostul Oh, I don't understand how I didn't thought about that! Thanks for your help, I'll try it.

Comment: Note: $[\Bbb Q(e^{2 \pi i/p}):\Bbb Q]=p-1$

Comment: @LukasHeger isn't it $p$ instead of $p-1$?

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso no, $p-1$ is correct.

Comment: @LukasHeger and how can I prove it? I have been trying it since yesterday and it feels impossible.

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso the minimal polynomial of $e^{2 \pi i/p}$ is $\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}$ which has degree $p-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try denoting $e^{i2\pi/p}=a$, and notice that $\cos(2\pi/p)=\frac{a+a^{-1}}{2}$.