# What algebraic number $k$ satisfy $\mathbb{Q}\left(k,\ i \right) \cong \mathbb{Q}\left(\text{exp} (2\pi i/5)\right)$?

Tags: ring-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $\alpha=\text{exp}(2\pi i/5)$.
I was trying to find an explicit relation between
$\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\{a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2+d\alpha^3 : a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{Q}\}$
and
$\mathbb{Q}(i,\ \sqrt{5})=\{(a+ib)+(c+id)\sqrt{5}:a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}\}$

Why $\sqrt{5}$ and $i$? I was able to find that $2x^2+(1-\sqrt{5})x+2$ is an irreducible minimal polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ with root $\alpha$. And
$$\alpha=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}+i\frac{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}{4}$$
$\alpha$ has $\sqrt{5}$ as you can see.

But I have trouble dealing with double sqrt in imaginary part, $\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}$.
$$\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}=\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{5}}+\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}$$
I found above relation by solving $x^2-10x+5=0$ but this process can't reduce double sqrt into single.

For $X=\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}$,
$$X^2-10=-2\sqrt{5}$$
shows $\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}$ is algebraic number of degree 2 in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$. Is this an implication that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ is not large enough to math up with $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$?
If it is, what algebraic number $k$ should I use to obtain the following?
$$\mathbb{Q}(k,i)\cong\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$$

Comment: $x^2+1\bmod 11$ is irreducible whereas $x^5-1\bmod 11$ splits completely.

Comment: Serious error on line 2. It should read:
$$\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)=\{a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2+d\alpha^3\mid a,b,c,d\in\Bbb{Q}\}.$$

Comment: And the answer to the question in the title is: *This fails for all $k$*. Simply because $i\notin \Bbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/5})$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes, sorry about that

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok that was full answer to me thanks.

Comment: @jjagmath Not so. $\sqrt5\in\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4079220/442

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: is there a simple way to know that $i\notin\mathbb{Q} (\alpha) $?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I can see that $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt {5})\subseteq \mathbb{Q} (\alpha) $. But how can one know that $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt {5})$ is the only field lying between $\mathbb {Q} $ and $\mathbb{Q} (\alpha) $?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The simplest answer comes from Galois correspondence. $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)/\Bbb{Q})\simeq \Bbb{Z}_5^*\simeq C_4$. The group $C_4$ has only a single non-trivial subgroup. By Galois correspondence this means that there is only a single intermediate field. $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ would be a different one, so cannot be an intermediate field.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: thanks, I checked up my blog posts on cyclotomic polynomials and found the same thing. I am not much familiar with Galois theory, but I understand the treatment for cyclotomic polynomials as given by Gauss using periods. Looks like I had forgotten the details a bit.